# Комбинации алфавита в слове С++

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм, комбинаторика

Не могу придумать алгоритм:
На вход дается алфавит, например: `a = {a,b, c, d};`
Дается размер слова, например `length = 10;`
Надо с помощью алфавита вывести все комбинации возможных слов длины length.
Естественно повторяться буквы могут.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слова в данном случае можно рассматривать как числа в 4-значной системе.
Можно перебрать все числа длиной `LENGTH`, просто прибавляя единичку, начиная с наименьшего числа (`'aaa'` в коде):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define LENGTH 3
#define FIRST_DIGIT 'a'
#define LAST_DIGIT 'b'


int main(void)
{
  char number[LENGTH+1];
  int i = 0;
  for ( ; i < LENGTH; ++i) /* start with 'aaa' */
    number[i] = FIRST_DIGIT;
  number[LENGTH] = '\0';

  for ( ; ; ) {
    puts(number);
    { /* increment the rightmost digit */
      int pos = LENGTH;
      char digit = number[--pos];
      for ( ; digit == LAST_DIGIT; digit = number[--pos]) {
        /* handle overflow */
        if (pos == 0)
          return 0; /* no more digits */
        number[pos] = FIRST_DIGIT; /* set to zero and increment the left neighbor*/
      }
      number[pos] = ++digit;
    }
  }
}
```

### Результат

```
aaa
aab
aba
abb
baa
bab
bba
bbb
```

В С гарантировано, что `a..d` подряд идут, поэтому `++digit` позволяет от `'a'` к `'b'` итд перейти.

Самая сложная часть в коде, это обработка переполнения. Например:

`2999 + 1` — так как `9` в конце находится, то последняя цифра обнуляется (`number[pos] = FIRST_DIGIT`) и цикл переходит налево и повторяет попытку увеличить цифру. Если левого соседа нет (`pos == 0`), то происходит выход из программы (все цифры равны `LAST_DIGIT`).

Вот C++ код, который поддерживает произвольный алфавит:

```cc
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  const char alphabet[] = "ab";
  const size_t last_digit = sizeof(alphabet) - 2; // '\0'
  const size_t length = 3;
  size_t number[length] = {0}; // indices into alphabet

  for ( ; ; ) {
    // print number
    for (auto i : number) std::cout << alphabet[i];
    std::cout << '\n';

    // increment the rightmost digit
    size_t pos = length;
    while (number[--pos] == last_digit) { // overflow
      if (pos == 0)
        return 0; // no more digits
      number[pos] = 0; // set to zero and increment the left neigbor
    }
    ++number[pos];
  }
}
```

Идея из [ответа @Steve Jessop на похожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3358245/4279).

Реализация на Си для произвольного алфавита:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  const char alphabet[] = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  const size_t last_digit = sizeof(alphabet) - 2; // '\0'
  const size_t length = (argc == 2) ? atoi(argv[1]) : 2;
  if (!length) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  size_t number[length]; // indices into alphabet
  for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) number[i] = 0;
  for ( ; ; ) {
    // print number
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) putchar(alphabet[number[i]]);
    putchar('\n');

    // increment the rightmost digit
    size_t pos = length;
    while (number[--pos] == last_digit) { // overflow
      if (pos == 0)
        return 0; // no more digits
      number[pos] = 0; // set to zero and increment the left neigbor
    }
    ++number[pos];
  }
}
```

[Пример](https://ideone.com/Xs1G0A).

Comment: Алгоритм переделал под себя, все работает, но 1 вопрос, если человек сам должен вводить длину получаемых комбинаций, т.е. сейчас стоит const size_t = 6; Мне же надо, чтобы человек сам вводил длину и в зависимости от ее значения начинал перебирать возможные варианты. Ошибку показывает на 'size_t number[length] = {0}'

Comment: пытался сделать number через указатель, тогда ругается на 
for(auto i: number) ... (подчеркивая number).
Ошибка: не найдена соответствующая функция begin.

Comment: @KamilNHOT: чтобы динамически длину задавать, можно vector использовать (с++ не разрешает массивам неконстантный размер иметь):  добавить `<vector>`, `<string>` заголовки и поправить код `main(int argc, char* argv[]) { const size_t length = argc > 1 ? std::stoul(argv[1]) : 3;
  std::vector<size_t> number(length, 0);`  всё остальное без изменений.

Comment: тупанул, тупанул (

Comment: Благодарю, все получилось! http://pastebin.com/Tyzz2miq

Answer (score 3):

Очень просто.
Заполняете все `a`.
Далее цикл с переносом - самый младший разряд, берете следующий символ из алфавита - это следующее слово.
Если его уже нет - ставите опять наименьшее, и переходите к следующему символу по старшинству (с той же процедурой).

Что-то типа такого, на коленке набросанного:

```
bool next(string& s, const string& al)
{
    bool carry = true;
    for(int i = 0; carry && i < s.length(); ++i)
    {
        char c = s[i];
        int pos = al.find(c);
        if (pos == al.length()-1)
        {
            carry = true;
            s[i] = al[0];
        }
        else
        {
            s[i] = al[pos+1];
            carry = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return !carry;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    string s("aaaa");
    do {
        cout << s << endl;
    } while(next(s,"abcd"));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Написался такой вот жутко обфусцированный код. Добро пожаловать, любители мозговыноса на C++. [Ideone](http://ideone.com/fXapYh)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iterator>

using Alphabet=std::set<char>;
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::setw;
using std::next;
using std::make_pair;

Alphabet::iterator next_combination(const Alphabet& alphabet,const string::iterator& pos)
{
    //находим в алфавите символ, который следует после символа, на который показывает pos
    const auto newpos=next(alphabet.find(*pos));
    //если такого символа нет - произошло переполнение. На место этого символа пишем первый символ алфавита, и начинаем сдвигать символ pos+1
    *pos =  *( newpos==alphabet.end() ? next_combination(alphabet,next(pos)) : newpos);
    //всегда возвращаем первый символ алфавита
    return begin(alphabet);
}

size_t intpower(const size_t base,size_t exp)
{
    size_t ret=1;
    for( ; exp-- ; ret*=base);
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    //входной алфавит
    const string alphabet_in="abcd";
    //длина выходной строки
    constexpr size_t length=4;
    //загоняем алфавит во множество, гарантируем тем самым, что в нем нет дублей
    const Alphabet alphabet(begin(alphabet_in),end(alphabet_in));
    //печатаем все комбинации
    for(
            //первоначально, заполняем массив первым символом алфавита
            auto context=make_pair(string(length,*alphabet.begin()),intpower(alphabet.size(),length));
                cout << setw(10) << context.second-- << '\t' << context.first << endl, //печатаем порядковый номер и комбинацию
                next_combination(alphabet,begin(context.first)),                //формируем следующую комбинацию
                context.second                                               //продолжаем, если счетчик оставшихся комбинаций отличен от 0
                                                                                                     ;
        );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А где обфускация? Красивый и понятный код на плюсах...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, эх, даже тернаркой и запятой впечатление не удалось испортить...

Comment: @gbg Надо было еще диграфы и триграфы вставить, было бы внушительнее.

Answer (score 1):

Проще выразить задачу в терминах цифр: вывести все числа с 10 цифрами в 4-значной системе. Вот полный пример для чисел 3-цифрами в двоичной системе:

```
aaa
aab
aba
abb
baa
bab
bba
bbb
```

Этот вывод можно получить, используя простую (но неэффективную) рекурсивную функцию, реализующую полный перебор:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char alphabet[] = "ab";
enum { base = sizeof(alphabet) - 1, length = 3 };
char number[length + 1];

void print_digits(int pos)
{
  if (length == pos) {
    puts(number);
  }
  else {
    int i = 0;
    for ( ; i < base; ++i) {
      number[pos] = alphabet[i];
      print_digits(pos + 1);
    }
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  print_digits(0);
  return 0;
}
```

Для случая в вопросе `alphabet = "abcd"` and `length = 10`.

Чтобы понять как это работает можно по уровням пройти по дереву вызовов для случая `alphabet = "01"; length = 3`:

[image: binary tree]

Сперва никакие позиции не заполнены `'___'`. На первом уровне заполняется первая позиция всеми возможными цифрами (двумя в данном случае). На втором уровне заполняется вторая позиция итд. Когда `length` позиций заполнено, число (в квадрате) выводится.