# Сумма двоичных чисел с++

Tags: c++

Нужно выполнить операцию сложения двоичных чисел. Начал писать код и запутался в логике, в итоге программа выводит просто строчку из нулей (функция суммы в самом конце кода)
Пришел к выводу, что наверное просто не понимаю, как осуществить сложение двоичных чисел, ибо весь мой код суммы состоит из набросков из кодов других программистов и своих додумок
Буду очень признателен, если подскажите хотя бы логику как это сделать или укажите на мои ошибки
p.s. сложить нужно именно два двоичных числа, а не сложить два десятичных и потом результат перевести в двоичный код.

```
  class BinaryTransformation  {   //класс для работы с двоичными числами
    private:

     int newNum1, newNum2;
     static const int bitsize = 8;

     int bits1[bitsize];
     int bits2[bitsize];
     int bitssum[bitsize];
     int p, k;

public:

    Calculate value, value1;

    void getNewNum(Calculate x, Calculate y) 
    {
        newNum1 = x.getValue();
        newNum2 = y.getValue1();
        cout << "newNum1 = " << newNum1 << endl;
        cout << "NewNum2 = " << newNum2 << endl;
    }



   void transformation1() 
   {

        for (int i = 0; i < bitsize; ++i) {
            if (newNum1 % 2 == 0) 
            {
                bits1[i] = 0;
            }
            else 
            {
                bits1[i] = 1;
            }
            newNum1 = newNum1/2;
        }

    }


    void showTransformation1()
    {
        for (int i = bitsize - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        {       
            cout << bits1[i];
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    void transformation2() 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < bitsize; ++j){

            if (newNum2 % 2 == 0)
            {
                bits2[j] = 0;
            }
            else {
                bits2[j] = 1;
            }

            newNum2 = newNum2 / 2;
        }

     }
    void showTransformation2() {
        for (int j = bitsize - 1; j >= 0; --j) 
        {

            cout << bits2[j];

        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    void bitSum() {

        for (int i = bitsize - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            p = 0;
            bitssum[i] = bits1[i]+bits2[i]+p;
            bitssum[i + 1] = k % 2;
            p = p / 2;

        }


    }
    void showBitSum() {

        for (int i = 0; i<= bitsize; --i)
        {
            cout << bitssum[i];

        }

        for (int i = bitsize - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            cout << bitssum[i];
        }

    }

};
    int main() {

        int a, b;

        Calculate n1;
        n1.setNum();
        n1.showNum();

        n1.sum();
        n1.sub();
        n1.mul();
        n1.div();

        n1.getValue();
        n1.getValue1();
        BinaryTransformation newNum1;


        newNum1.getNewNum(n1, n1);
        newNum1.transformation1();
        newNum1.showTransformation1();
        newNum1.transformation2();
        newNum1.showTransformation2();
        newNum1.bitSum();
        newNum1.showBitSum();
        system("pause");
        return 0;
```

Comment: Используйте встроенный оператор `+` над типом данных `int`. Двоичное число или недвоичное, это свойство строкового представления числа, а не самого числа[.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/453059/10105)

Comment: int в с++ уже в двоичном виде хранится, поэтому `a+b` именно двоичные числа складывает (в зависимости от представления, конкретные операции над битами могут быть разными даже концептуально). Хотя за исключением крайних случаев, не важно как реализовано, пока ответ верный возвращается. Если вы в образовательных целях хотите по одному биту складывать (то что в железе обычно реализовано), то явно словами опишите какое вы представление целых используете -- конечное/бесконечное количество бит, как у вас отрицательные числа представлены, Не используйте сломанный код в качестве спецификации задачи.

Comment: вот [реализация `++i` для произвольной системы счисления  (подставьте "01" вместо "ab")](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/526493/23044). Вот [пример, как `a*b` реализовать, имея `a+=b` операцию и побитовые сдвиги: `a>>=1`, `b<<=1`](https://ideone.com/riQ0mh). Упрощённая версия этого алгоритма может быть использована, чтобы `a+b` реализовать, имея `a+=1`.

Answer (score 2):

Фрагмент кода из книги "Elements of Programming Interviews_ The Insiders’ Guide (2015)". Функция выполняет побитовое "сложение столбиком".

```cpp
    unsigned sum(unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
    {
      unsigned s = 0;
      unsigned carryin = 0; // перенос из предыдущего разряда
      unsigned k = 1; // маска для получения самого младшего бита
      unsigned temp_a = a;
      unsigned temp_b = b;

      while (temp_a || temp_b)
      {
        // извлечение самых младших битов
        unsigned ak = a & k, bk = b & k;

        // вычисляем бит который переносится в следующий разряд
        unsigned carryout = (ak & bk) | (ak & carryin) | (kb & carryin);

        // комбинация двух складываемых битов
        // и бита перенесенного из предыдущего разряда
        s |= (ak ^ bk ^ carryin);

        // то что будет перенесено в следующий разряд
        carryin = carryout << 1;

        // сдвигаем маску на один бит влево
        k <<= 1;

        // отрезаем уже обработанные младшие биты
        // остатки используются для контроля продолжения цикла
        temp_a >>= 1, temp_b >>= 1;
      }

      return s | carryin;
    }
```

Comment: Вот здесь `unsigned carryout = (ak & bk) | (ak & carryin) | (kb & carryin);` в книге опечатка (правильно -- `... | (bk & carryin)`)