# Генерация последовательной строки Bash

Tags: строки, bash

Нужно сгенерировать восьмизначную строку использую символы a-z и 0-9:

```
00000000
00000001
00000002
...
zzzzzzzy
zzzzzzzz
```

Возможно так:

```
for x in {{a..z},{0..9}}
do
    echo $x
done
```

Comment: @jfs Неверное сокращение - восьмизначную.

Comment: `37**8` всё равно много строк печатать. Зачем вам столько строк? Что вы с ними делать собираетесь?

Comment: Печатать их вовсе не обязательно, должна генерироваться строка ( что не вышло), затем тестироваться(эта часть уже готова) и выводиться некоторый результат.

Comment: вот на C++ программка: [`./a.out <<<8`](https://ideone.com/xQIcMb) из [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/526493/23044)

Comment: вот [тоже самое на Си](https://ideone.com/Xs1G0A) (часов за 10 все строки вывести может ~100MB/s)

Comment: Спасибо, попробую сначала сгенерировать таблицу, а после провести тесты.

Comment: про 10 часов я ошибся, более реальная оценка 3 дня: `((8+1)*36**8)/(100*(1<<20))/86400`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{{a..z},{0..9}}
```

сгенерирует всего лишь одно знакоместо:

```
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

---

вам надо повторить конструкцию столько раз, сколько знакомест вам необходимо.

пример на более короткой последовательности:

```
$ echo {{a..b},{0..1}}
a b 0 1
$ echo {{a..b},{0..1}}{{a..b},{0..1}}
aa ab a0 a1 ba bb b0 b1 0a 0b 00 01 1a 1b 10 11
$ echo {{a..b},{0..1}}{{a..b},{0..1}}{{a..b},{0..1}}
aaa aab aa0 aa1 aba abb ab0 ab1 a0a a0b a00 a01 a1a a1b a10 a11 baa bab ba0 ba1 bba bbb bb0 bb1 b0a b0b b00 b01 b1a b1b b10 b11 0aa 0ab 0a0 0a1 0ba 0bb 0b0 0b1 00a 00b 000 001 01a 01b 010 011 1aa 1ab 1a0 1a1 1ba 1bb 1b0 1b1 10a 10b 100 101 11a 11b 110 111
```

---

восемь знаков из требуемого вами диапазона будут генерироваться и выводиться очень долго. вот генерация всего лишь четырёх на достаточно производительной рабочей станции занимает около десяти секунд:

```
$ time echo {{a..z},{0..9}}{{a..z},{0..9}}{{a..z},{0..9}}{{a..z},{0..9}} > /dev/null

real    0m9.937s
user    0m9.808s
sys 0m0.124s
```

---

к тому же, судя по всему, программа *bash* не будет выводить ничего, пока не сформирует всю эту огромную строку (длиной `36^8*9` байт, около 23 терабайт). на формирование которой вполне может не хватить оперативной памяти вкупе с файлом подкачки.

потому, вероятно, имеет смысл сделать восемь вложенных циклов, каждый из которых будет формировать по одному знаку для результата:

```
for d1 in {{a..z},{0..9}}; do
  ...
  for d8 in {{a..z},{0..9}}; do
    echo $d1$d2$d3$d4$d5$d6$d7$d8
  done
  ...
done
```

это будет работать, скорее всего, дольше, чем прямое перечисление, но зато не потребует наличия терабайтов в оперативной памяти или файле подкачки.

Comment: Возможно ускорить генерацию?

Comment: на интерпретируемом "на лету", без какой-либо предкомпиляции, языке - вряд ли. собственно на любом языке программирования такой сумасшедший объём информации обрабатывать довольно затруднительно.

Comment: восемь символов из набора из 36, плюс один символ-разделитель - это 36^8*9 байт. примерно 23 терабайта информации.

Comment: если я правильно понимаю, эта команда ничего не выводит пока все строки не созданы (просто ест память и процессор нагружает). У меня не получилось даже 5 цифр таким образом вывести.

Comment: @jfs, тем хуже для автора вопроса. он явно пытается сделать "что-то не то или не так".

Comment: это проблема с предложенным в ответе подходом. К примеру, [Си код](https://ideone.com/Xs1G0A) все 5-значные цифры за 3 секунды выводит.

Comment: @jfs, вопрос-то был про скрипт для интерпретатора bash. что, вкупе с вашим предложением, говорит именно о том, что автор "что-то делает не так". кстати, я дополнил ответ некоторым подобием обхода (по крайней мере в отношении оперативной памяти).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Уже думал про вложенные циклы. Похоже это лучший вариант, спасибо.

Comment: да, конечно, поэтому я Си код, только в виде комментария опубликовал, а не в виде ответа. Попробовал циклы: работают (в 200 раз медленнее, но это ожидаемо).